# how to add list of objects to html table in spring MVC project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm really new to Spring MVC and Hibernate and this is my first project with java ee technologies. I’m stuck at this point for almost 2 days and I searched over internet but no luck. What I only got is how to represent list of objects in html table fetched from database(which I'm not looking for).

I have a one to many relationship in my project with FeedOrderDetails and Feed. Everything works perfectly fine except I can’t save many feeds with feedOrderDetails. Case is  I can save only defined number of feed items in the my jsp page.
Here is a picture of my ER diagram.
[image]

This is the code in my jsp

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><form:input path="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td><form:input path="discount" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><form:input path="total" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].unitPrice" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].quantity" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Feed</td>
            <td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].feed.id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add Feed"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form:form>
```

What I want to achieve is I want to add many feeds to Feed Order and save it all together. Like I want to add feed Id, feed name ,quantity and unit price to html table and save all these details in one button click.

this is what I want to achieve.
[image]

I enter packing material ID,quantity and unit price and click add button to add those item to table. like that I want to add those item to a table in html form with path tag included in it.
for a example 
first row should contain tag
    `<td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].feed.id" /></td>`

second row

```
`<td><form:input path="feedOrderDetail[1].feed.id" /></td>`
```

whenever I add items to table this should happen.

Comment: I want to add rows to a html table not the fetch the data from database like said in my question. can I do that with foreach?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: You can send two objects to your controller : feed and feedOrderDetail using @ModelAttribute twice. Then you can add feedOrderDetail to Feed's feedOrderDetails list and save Feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem with javascript. hope it will help to someone else later.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var counts = rowCount - 1;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var feed = document.createElement("input");
    feed.type = "text";
    feed.name = "feedOrderDetail[" + counts + "].feed.id";
    cell1.appendChild(feed);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var unitPrice = document.createElement("input");
    unitPrice.type = "text";
    unitPrice.name = "feedOrderDetail[" + counts + "].unitPrice";
    cell2.appendChild(unitPrice);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var quantity = document.createElement("input");
    quantity.type = "text";
    quantity.name = "feedOrderDetail[" + counts + "].quantity";
    cell3.appendChild(quantity);

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write some javascript to add form `<input>` elements with the names resembling to those produced with `<form:input>` tags and then submit them altogether. It involves a bit of js coding, once the form elements are properly set, springmvc will do the conversion into a parent+list of children. In this context, elements like `<form:input path="feedOrderDetail[0].feed.id" />` will be redundant if there's one `<form:input path="id"/>`

You can see an example [here](http://apps.mattfleming.com/DynamicFormsExample/test.html).